# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number[ask]

Tags: php, pdo

Please help me! I have a trouble with error

> PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

I use the query:

```
public function SaveStep1($data)

    $id = intval($data['id']);  

    $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `user_general_info` SET `soname` = :soname, `last_soname` = :last_soname, `name` = :name, 
        `middle_name` = :middle_name, `birthday` = :birthday, `birthplace` = :birthplace, `city_code` = :city_code,
        `city` = :city, `street` = :street, `house` = : house, `corp` = :corp, `litera` = :litera, `flat` = :flat WHERE `id` = :id");
    $query->bindParam(":soname", $data[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(":last_soname", $data[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(":name", $data[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(":middle_name", $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(":birthday", $data[5], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(":birthplace", $data[6], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(":city_code", $data[7], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(":city", $data[8], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(":street", $data[9], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(":house", $data[10], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(":corp", $data[11], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(":litera", $data[12], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(":flat", $data[13], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(":id", $data['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    //print_r($data[0]);

    return $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the SQL statement:

```
`house` = : house
```

should be

```
`house` = :house
```